# plot several linegraphs in one image using R

Tags: r, loops, graph

I am an absolute beginner in R. so this is probably a stupid question.
I have a table like this (csv format):

```
,1A+,2A+,3A-,3A+,5A-,5A+,6A-,6A+,7A-,7A+
6,4.530309305,5.520356001,3.437626731,5.146758132,,4.355022819,,4.191337618,,4.076583859
10,8.697814022,9.765817956,,9.636004092,3.725756716,8.600484774,3.457423715,8.358842335,2.246622784,7.244668991
12,,,8.176341701,,,,,,,
17,,,,,6.24785396,,5.077069513,,3.137524578
```

I want to create a line graph in R plotting all the different Y values (1A+, 2A+, etc) vs the Y values (6,10,12,17).

I am doing:

```
new_curves   <- read.csv("new_curves_R.csv", as.is = TRUE)
g_range <- range(0,new_curves$X)
axis(2, las=1, at=4*0:g_range[2])
plot(new_curves$X1A.,new_curves$X,type="o", col="blue")
legend(1, g_range[2], c("new_curves$X1A."), cex=0.8, col=c("blue"));
title(xlab="Days", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
title(ylab="Total", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
```

However, this (obviously) only plots the first datapoint. (the legend is not working for some reason either). I am guessing I need some sort of for loop to add each Y value to the graph recursively. Likewise, a loop would be needed to make the legend.

thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `matplot` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- read.table(text=", 1A+,2A+,3A-,3A+,5A-,5A+,6A-,6A+,7A-,7A+
6,4.530309305,5.520356001,3.437626731,5.146758132,,4.355022819,,4.191337618,,4.076583859
10,8.697814022,9.765817956,,9.636004092,3.725756716,8.600484774,3.457423715,8.358842335,2.246622784,7.244668991
12,,,8.176341701,,,,,,,
17,,,,,6.24785396,,5.077069513,,3.137524578", header=TRUE, sep=",", fill=TRUE)

matplot(dat[1], dat[-1])
```

Comment: I edited the code to read "matplot(dat[1], dat[-1], type="o")". This adds lines to datapoints. However, I have several N/A values. Is there any way to force matplot to connect those lines anyway?

Comment: I think you would need `segments` to do that. The convention in R is not to plot lines when there is missing data.